# iOS 11 + Xcode 9.0 = No Audio Units

Tags: ios, xcode, ios11, audiounit, xcode9

Need help with Audio Units in iOS 11. I have two iOS apps: an app that provides a V3 Audio Unit, and a host app for Audio Units. The problem is that when I compile the host application in Xcode 9.0 with iOS 11 SDK and run it on an iPhone with iOS 11, the **host application doesn't see the Audio Unit**.

I made some research and here's what I got:
The problem affects any audio unit app, not only these two specific apps. You can easily see the same problem if you use an *AudioUnitV3Example* project from the Apple's website (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AudioUnitV3Example/Introduction/Intro.html). This sample project consists of two apps: *iOSAUv3Host*, and *iOSFilterDemoApp* that provides an Audio Unit App Extension. You need to install both applications on your iOS device.

When you launch *AUv3Host* app, it will show you a list of all Audio Units available in the system:

- on iOS 10, there are 16 Audio Units available—15 default audio units
  by Apple, and FiltedDemo audio unit by Demo.
- on iOS 11, there are only 15 Audio Units—15 default Audio units by
  Apple. The AUv3Host app doesn't see the FiltedDemo Audio Unit (See
  screenshots).

[image: iOS 10 and iOS 11 screenshots] 
I also downloaded Xcode 8.3.3 with iOS 10 SDK (from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/) and tried all possible configurations of build SDK's and device's iOS version. Here's what I got:

- *FiltedDemo* built by iOS 11 SDK + *AUv3Host* built by iOS 11 SDK + iOS 11 device = BAD (No FiltedDemo)
- *FiltedDemo* built by iOS 10 SDK + *AUv3Host* built by iOS 11 SDK + iOS 11 device = BAD (No FiltedDemo)
- *FiltedDemo* built by iOS 11 SDK + *AUv3Host* built by iOS 10 SDK + iOS 11 device = OK (FiltedDemo exists)
- *FiltedDemo* built by iOS 10 SDK + *AUv3Host* built by iOS 10 SDK + iOS 11 device = OK (FiltedDemo exists)
- *FiltedDemo* built by iOS 11 SDK + *AUv3Host* built by iOS 11 SDK + iOS 10 device = OK (FiltedDemo exists)
- *FiltedDemo* built by iOS 10 SDK + *AUv3Host* built by iOS 11 SDK + iOS 10 device = OK (FiltedDemo exists)
- *FiltedDemo* built by iOS 11 SDK + *AUv3Host* built by iOS 10 SDK + iOS 10 device = OK (FiltedDemo exists)
- *FiltedDemo* built by iOS 10 SDK + *AUv3Host* built by iOS 10 SDK + iOS 10 device = OK (*FiltedDemo* exists)

So, it looks like the problem appears only when BOTH conditions is valid: device have iOS 11 installed, and the host app is compiled with the iOS 11 SDK. Audio Unit compilation doesn't affect the problem.

Do you have any ideas how to fix this? And is there a way I could fix this, or it's an iOS 11 SDK bug, and this can be fixed by Apple only?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem solved. I also submited the issue as a bug at bugreport.apple.com, and I've just got the answer from the Apple team:

> Engineering has requested the following information regarding your bug
>   report:  Please add the Inter-App Audio Capability to your
>   application. This is a privacy requirement and was mentioned during
>   the WWDC talk.  Since the AUv3Host requires self-signing the
>   entitlement is lost.   All AUv3 hosts require the Inter-App Audio
>   entitlement to see v3 audio units. We will look into how to make this
>   even more explicit and will update the sample to avoid these issues.

This works like a charm. iOS 11 device is now able to see all the 16 Audio Units, including the *FiltedDemo*.
[image: Problem fixed]

It would be nice if this requirement was more obvious. I hope that Apple will update their documentation and the sample project.